# Non static method in Java

Tags: java, static

I have User class with field like login, password etc.

In method i tryed to  get acces to field:

```
preparedStmt.setString(1, User.getid());
```

but is the error

```
non static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: Well presumably `User.getId()` is an instance method - you've got to indicate *which* user's ID you want...

Comment: In future, please search before asking a question - in this case, to find the duplicate I just put the error message into Stack Overflow, and it found *lots* of hits. (This is a fairly common issue.)

Answer (score 1):

`getid()` is not `static` and therefore can only be called on an *instance* of `User`, not on `User` itself.

```
User someUser = ...;
preparedStmt.setString(1, someUser.getid());
```

Comment: Look on my main method:                                                     User us1 = new User("91");
        db.setUser(us1); //insert